# tshark not recognizing wpa psk option

Tags: wireshark, tshark, sniffing, linux

I'm trying to decrypt captured wpa-psk traffic with tshark, but it's not recognizing the option I'm trying to override. This option allows me to specify a PSK to use for decrypting. I'm using tshark 1.8.1 from the Backtrack R3.

```
# tshark -o wlan.wep_key1:wpa-pwd:foo:bar
tshark: -o flag "wlan.wep_key1:wpa-pwd:foo:bar" specifies unknown preference
```

It appears from other posts that this option has worked before ([here](https://superuser.com/questions/413225/wireshark-wpa-4-way-handshake) and [here](http://www.lovemytool.com/blog/2010/05/wireshark-and-tshark-decrypt-sample-capture-file-by-joke-snelders.html)).

Answer (score 0):

That option seems to have changed as of 1.8; here is the new syntax:

```
 tshark  -o wlan.enable_decryption:TRUE -o "uat:80211_keys:\"wpa-pwd\",\"{PASS}:{SSID}\"" ...
```

You do need the quote escaping as shown, and obviously substitute {PASS} and {SSID}.